# Can I copy the content from GridLayout in android?

Tags: android, grid-layout, android-gridlayout, gridlayoutmanager, android-viewgroup

Is there any way in android to copy and paste GridLayout as same as Textview did?
I have the GridLayout inside of LinearLayout. Inside of gridlayout, I have added more than one textviews. 
I need to copy all the content inside from that gridlayout. Is this possible? If yes, how can I achieve?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1):

Yes,you can do it.
First you should go to the xml view of the grid layout and then you can copy more effectively.

Comment: Thanks :-). But, I want to copy the views' content from on screen as same as we do copy from textview.